# Update tables with one SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this main `Product` table:

```
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "user_id", length = 20)
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "title", length = 75)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "meta_title", length = 100)
    private String metaTitle;

    @Column(name = "status", length = 100)
    private String status;
}
```

Additional table for storing categories that should be returned as List:

```
@Table(name = "product_category")
public class ProductCategory implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "product_id", length = 4)
    private Integer productId;

    @Column(name = "category_id", length = 20)
    private Integer categoryId;

}
```

Additional table for storing Payment Methods that should be returned as List:

```
@Table(name = "product_payment_methods")
public class ProductPaymentMethods implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "product_id", length = 20)
    private Integer productId;

    @Column(name = "payment_methods", length = 20000)
    private String paymentMethods;
}
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
INNER JOIN product_category ON Product.id = product_category.productId
INNER JOIN product_payment_methods ON Product.id = product_payment_methods.productId
WHERE userId = 1
```

I use this DTO to update the data:

```
public class ProductFullDTO {

    private int id;

    private Integer userId;

    private List<Integer> categories;

    private List<String> paymentMethods;
}
```

How I can update the data into tables using one SQL update query?

Comment: what do you mean by update?  does that include adding or removing categories or payment methods?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Product p
INNER JOIN product_category pc ON p.id = pc.productId
INNER JOIN product_payment_methods ppm ON p.id = ppm.productId
SET p.a = 'something',
    pc.b = 42,
    ppm.c = pc.c
WHERE userId = 1
```

With your SELECT you can determine which rows will be affected

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
INNER JOIN product_category ON Product.id = product_category.productId
INNER JOIN product_payment_methods ON Product.id = product_payment_methods.productId
WHERE userId = 1
```

All rows from this query would become the data written in the update query

```
SET p.a = 'something',
    pc.b = 42,
    ppm.c = pc.c
```

As you can see you can combine the data from different tables and update any column with data from the row in the result set.

UPDATE queries should always be tested in a test environment.

Comment: I'm using Spring data - HQL. Is it possible to implement the UPDATE query using HQL?

Comment: yes see chapter 6 in https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-dynamic-mapping but i personally didn't do it.